# Get data from database odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Which is the simplest way to show data in xml from res_users_log table in custom module?

SELECT id, create_uid, create_date, write_date, write_uid
  FROM res_users_log

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do. Could you explain with more details?

Comment: @ChesuCR load data from databse in my .xml form, this data https://postimg.org/image/y9ye5iru5/ show in xml in list view.

Comment: Just create a tree form with the fields you want to show. You can check examples in the source code of Odoo

Comment: @ChesuCR any link example?

Comment: You should read the docs. https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/backend.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you

```
def _get_users_log(self):
    SQL = ('select * from res_users_log')
    self.env.cr.execute(SQL)
    for row in self.env.cr.fetchall():
            return row
```